# getting current location wrong?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

I'm new in Android development and I want to learn from my mistakes but I first need to understand what am I doing wrong here:
I'm trying to get my current location

```
locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

                loc.getLatitude();
                loc.getLongitude();

                LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
                CameraUpdate currentLocation = CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 16);
                mMap.animateCamera(currentLocation);

                String Text = "My current location is: " +
                        "Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() +
                        "Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude();
                Log.d("Dana","acc="+loc.getAccuracy());

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }
        };
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    1);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    1);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                0, 0, locationListener);
```

but on simulator and also on my real device my location is somewhere in England, even if my phone has location activated. Why is this happening? Why is not retrieving my current real location? I've logged the accuracy and it's just 20...

Also, is there a way to store that location, even if the activity is closed? Because I've seen that when I just close the activity and reopen it doesn't call again the onLocationChanged function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you inside closed building or something, try to go out with your device and see. As you know GPS works better out in open.

Answer (score 0):

if you want, you might use GoogleLocationAPI instead of this, I think, it is more efficient than you did use. search on google, you will find examples.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: If you couldn't solve this problem please text me, I will help out you.